# Notice: Undefined index: file uploading video

Tags: php, html, html5-video

I am trying to upload a video to my uploads folder. I got the code from another question on here and that works fine. But I keep getting this notice error and I don't know how to fix it. I've been trying all day. I tried to check if it was `isset()` and that still didn't work. Can someone help me please ?

```
<?php

$allowedExts = array("jpg", "jpeg", "gif", "png", "mp3", "mp4", "wma");
$_FILES = $_FILES['file'];
$extension = pathinfo($_FILES['file']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$unique = date('Y-m-d_H-i-s');

if ((null !==($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "video/mp4")
    || (null !==($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "audio/mp3"))
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "audio/wma")
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg"))

&& ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 2000000)
&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts)) {

    if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0) {

        echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br />";

    } else {

    echo 'File uploaded successfully';

    if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"])) {

        echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";

    } else {

        $datetime = date('Y-m-d_H-i-s');

        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
        "uploads/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . $datetime . md5($_FILES["file"]["name"]));

    }
    }

} else {

    echo "Invalid file";
}
?>

<form action="profile.php" id="videoupload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<label for="file"><span>Filename:</span></label>
<input type="file" name="file" id="file" /> 
<br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />

</form>
```

Comment: The first place I'd look is that `$_FILES = $_FILES['file'];` line. You might have done that for a reason, but the rest of your script is acting like that didn't happen.

Comment: @rickdenhaan when i keep that line, the only place I get that message is on that line. When I move it I get the message in about 3 other places.

Comment: Ok, that means `$_FILES['file']` doesn't exist at the start of your script and that line is not accidentally destroying it. Then the problem appears to be with whatever is supplying the file upload to this script, like a form with a `<input type="file">` or a piece of javascript. Can you add that part of your code to your question?

Comment: @rickdenhaan I just updated it

Comment: Just to clarify: the form is in the same file just like this? If that's the case, I assume you get the notice on the `$_FILES = $_FILES['file']` line when you *haven't* submitted the form yet, and after you do submit the form you still get the notice, but on a different line (the pathinfo() line I guess), correct?

Comment: The problem only shows up when I first load the page. When I submit the form the notices aren't there

Comment: Right. That's because you're trying to process the form when it hasn't been submitted yet. Wrap the whole block of PHP code from the `$allowedExts` line to the `}` after `echo "Invalid file";` in an if-statement to check that the form was submitted. You could use `if (isset($_FILES['file']))` or something like `if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST")` for example.

Comment: I still think that line I mentioned first shouldn't be there, though.

Comment: Ok I moved that line and it still works. I'll wrap it up in an isset

Comment: Ok I wrapped it up in isset() and I am getting this notice `Notice: Undefined index: file` on this line `$extension = pathinfo($_FILES['file']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);`

Comment: Can you `var_dump($_FILES);` to see what's in there (if anything)?

Comment: I just put that part inside of the `if(isset)...` and theres no error there. Is it ok to do that ?

Comment: The entire block of PHP code that handles the file upload should be inside that if-statement.

Comment: @rickdenhaan ahhh ok thanks it works now. if you answer the question i'll accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to process the file upload before a file is uploaded. You have to check if the form was posted first.

```
<?php

if (isset($_FILES['file'])) {
    $allowedExts = array("jpg", "jpeg", "gif", "png", "mp3", "mp4", "wma");
    // $_FILES = $_FILES['file'];  // <-- remove this line
    $extension = pathinfo($_FILES['file']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    $unique = date('Y-m-d_H-i-s');

    if ((null !==($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "video/mp4")
        || (null !==($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "audio/mp3"))
        || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "audio/wma")
        || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
        || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
        || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg"))

    && ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 2000000)
    && in_array($extension, $allowedExts)) {

        if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0) {

            echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br />";

        } else {

            echo 'File uploaded successfully';

            if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"])) {

                echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";

            } else {

                $datetime = date('Y-m-d_H-i-s');

                move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
                "uploads/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . $datetime . md5($_FILES["file"]["name"]));

            }
        }

    } else {

        echo "Invalid file";
    }
}
?>

<form action="profile.php" id="videoupload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<label for="file"><span>Filename:</span></label>
<input type="file" name="file" id="file" /> 
<br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$_FILES['file']
```

means you have input type = file named 'file'. if you don't have the input named 'file', you got an undefined index notice.
if you have that,

```
$_FILES = $_FILES['file'];
```

this will bring error to other codes. because it try to override $_FILES.